# Authenticating to a Github remote with name and password

Tags: xcode, git, github

I need upload project to friend's github account. I have login and password. When I try to push project it's always ask name and password, I try to type login and password or main directory of github (paint out on screen with black) with password, try with empty password, but always take alert that it is incorrect name or password. I try to create repo on github and clone it to my Mac and then copy files to this cloned repo and after commit - push. But again I need type name and password. What is it? Some screens:

```
repo on github
```

[image]

```
add repo in xcode
```

[image]

```
What I need type in this fields?
```

[image]

Try type login and password, title of main directory and password,
  git-password, and all this names with empty password field. Always I see:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the SSH URL, which requires you to (generate and) register a public RSA key with Github before you can authenticate.

If this is a one-time thing, you can just switch to the HTTPS URL (see the repo's page on github), which allows you to authenticate with the github username and password combo.

**Edit:**

- For more information about how to generate and use SSH keys, check out [Github's SSH help articles](https://help.github.com/categories/56/articles)
- For a detailed comparison of the transport protocols supported by Git and their advantages and disadvantages, with respect to Github, see [this comparative article](https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747)